# Why was this question migrated

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[This question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/looking-to-undelete-an-answer) was just migrated from meta to meta workplace. I understand the question is referring to a post on this particular site but aren't these request usually treated here ?

Correct me if I'm wrong but the rules of undeleting and reopening are the same for all sites of the network right ? (Maybe beta sites are different...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I migrated the question as it is about a specific answer on a specific site - it is not a network wide (or Stack Overflow specific) issue.

It is specific to The Workplace and should be handled by that community.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding how this is proper to that website.  This post is still about "How do I get a stack exchange post undeleted" ..Maybe I don't get how un-deleting works. Is it proper to the Workplace's admins choice ? In that case makes sense.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname he didn't ask in general, but rather how to undelete his specific answer.

Comment: What constitutes a good answer is different on different sites. The answer was deleted for reasons specific to that community and the decision to undelete it is within the same community. @insertcleverxmasname

Comment: Alright good nuff for me.